# The space obtained by identifying the antipodal points of a circle

Tags: general-topology

Take the unit circle $S^1$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and partition it into subsets which contain exactly two points, the points being antipodal (at opposite ends of a diameter). $P$ is the resulting identification space.

Now, what is homeomorphic to $P$? My intuition says that it must be a semicircle. But couldn't construct a homeomorphism.

Comment: What space exactly do you mean by "semicircle"?

Comment: The set consisting of points of the upper/lower half of the unit circle

Comment: can you show that it is homeomorphic to a circle?

Comment: Should we consider this a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/298879/264 ?

Comment: Topologically, it's a circle, BUT when you do this with the $2$-sphere, the quotient space is not another $2$-spere, but a non-orientable surface: the projective plane.

Comment: The space you describe arises naturally as the domain of the trigonometric tangent function $tan$, and I thought this was some sort of exotic space, but the answers on this page reveal it's just the topological circle, again...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Identify antipodal points on the circle:

[image]

Form the identification space:

[image]

Moving along this space, you come back to where you started... just like on a circle:

[image]

(original gifs [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYsBW.gif) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX8V8.gif); I joined them because when they load at different times in the browser, they don't stay in sync)

This correspondence between the points of $P$ and the points of $S^1$ is a homeomorphism.

```
PlotUpTo[angle_, colorscale_] := 
 ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, angle}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.05],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[colorscale (Arg[-x - I y] + Pi)/(2 Pi )]],
 PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImageSize -> {300}, Axes -> None]

AnimatedMarker[time_, speed_] := Graphics[{PointSize[0.05], 
 Point[{Cos[speed 2 Pi time], Sin[speed 2 Pi time]}],
 White, PointSize[0.03], Point[{Cos[speed 2 Pi time], Sin[speed 2 Pi time]}]}]

AnimatedPlot[angle_, colorscale_, time_, speed_] := 
 Show[PlotUpTo[angle, colorscale], AnimatedMarker[time, speed]]

Export["animation.gif", Table[Rasterize[
 TableForm[{{AnimatedPlot[Pi, 2, t, 1/2]}, {AnimatedPlot[2 Pi, 1, t, 1]}},
 TableSpacing -> {10, 0}]], {t, 0, 1, 0.01}], "DisplayDurations" -> {0.04}]
```

Answer (score 19):

Start with $S^1$, as in the first figure below. Hold it at $c'$ and $c$, and flip the righthand side over to form an $\infty$ sign, as in the second figure. Now fold the loops together into a single loop, as in the third figure. Everything matches up properly to give you your quotient space: it’s $S^1$ again.

[image]

Comment: Prof. Scott Is it possible to do something similar with $S^2$ (two-sphere)?

Comment: @JanG: Not really. The resulting object is the [real projective plane](https://www.open.edu/openlearn/science-maths-technology/mathematics-statistics/surfaces/content-section-3.3), a non-orientable surface that cannot be embedded in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the very useful link.

Comment: Prof. Scott Would you mind to look on my new question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4693707/1003573?

Comment: @JanG: I looked, but I’m afraid that I can’t be of any help with that: it’s in an area about which I know virtually nothing.

Comment: That's OK, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 10):

Consider the (complex) function $f(z) = z^2$ from the circle onto itself (seeing the plane as the complex plane). This identifies exactly the antipodal points on the circle. So this map induces a homeomporphism between $S^1$ modulo this equivalence and $S^1$.

Answer (score 7):

I think your space is homeomorphic to the real projective line $\mathbb{R}P^1$.

$\mathbb{R}P^1$ is space of one dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Look at [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_line), as you can see real projective line is homeomorphic to $S^1$. So what you get after your construction is circle again.

In fact if you do your construction in more dimensions. Take $S^n$ and glue antipodal points and you get $\mathbb{R}P^n$. But for example in two dimensions $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is not homeomorphic to sphere since real projective plane has genus 1.