# Imagining $S^1$ with antipodal points identified

Tags: general-topology, circles

How can I imagine $S^1$ with antipodal points identified?
Are there more ways, say a few rendering nearby points nearby, and some other not?

And yet a smooth version?

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433912/the-space-obtained-by-identifying-the-antipodal-points-of-a-circle?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

**Big Hint**: Denote elements of $S^1/\{\pm 1\}$ by $[z]$ where $z$ is a representative in $S^1$. Then, consider the map $f:S^1/\{\pm 1\}\to S^1$, $[z]\mapsto z^2$. Show that this is a diffeomorphism.